# How does Excel's VLOOKUP handle multi-word lookup values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet that's returning unexpected `VLOOKUP` results, and I'm trying to narrow down the issue. I've run into a question I can't answer in my search for the solution.

Consider:
I have a lookup field that contains a list of Countries. If one of the entries in the list is `Great Britain`, does `VLOOKUP` analyze the ENTIRE string in the cell? or just the first word?

Consider Further:
If I have `United States` in a cell, and I'm comparing that value to my `VLOOKUP` set, what happens when I encounter `United Arab Emirates`? Does the lookup stop because it matched `United`? or does it continue because it's trying to match the String `United States` against a lookup value of `United States`?

Is it best to enclose lookup terms that include spaces in single or double quotes, or even do a comparison based on cell values with spaces stripped out of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` have 2 match modes - exact and approximate. They have many details greatly listed in the origin: [VLOOKUP Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx). However, 2 qoutes are quite relevant to the question:

> When searching **text** values in the first column of table_array, ensure
>   that the data in the first column of table_array does not have leading
>   spaces, trailing spaces, inconsistent use of straight ( ' or " ) and
>   curly ( ‘ or “) quotation marks, or nonprinting characters. In these
>   cases, VLOOKUP may give an incorrect or unexpected value.

And one more:

> If range_lookup is **FALSE** and lookup_value is **text**, then you can use
>   the **wildcard characters**, question mark (?) and asterisk (*), in
>   lookup_value. A question mark matches any single character; an
>   asterisk matches any sequence of characters. If you want to find an
>   actual question mark or asterisk, type a tilde (~) preceding the
>   character.

So, depending on what are your needs, just specify desired options and use wildcards as described. Hope that was helpful!

Comment: wow, didn't know you can use wildcards in VLOOKUP/MATCH! +1! (So you can catch up here! ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you simply forgot to provide `FALSE` (or `0` for the short version) as the 4th parameter of `VLOOKUP`. This will set it to exact match mode, i.e. it'll check each entry in your first column for a full match.

If you leave out the `FALSE`, Excel assumes your first column is sorted - and applies a binary search algorithm that is much more efficient - but will deliver the wrong results if its not sorted or if the element is not contained in the list. For further details see my [explanations here](https://superuser.com/questions/547083/how-do-you-speed-up-searching-large-columns-in-excel/547100#547100).