# How can I flag the presence/absence of a specific substring within a string in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

We have a list of keywords associated with a list of documents. The list was created from frequency counts of the words in the document text. We are trying to add a weight to the keywords based on whether or not they appear in the document name or not. For instance, if we had a document called `Agency_Solutions.doc`, then the keyword `agency` would sort higher on the list than `telephone`.

To complicate matters, every document has either `the`, `a`, `an` as it's top keyword, based on counts. Of course all that needs to be excluded; I've set up a `VLOOKUP` column with 171 'common' words for exclusion.

Here's my problem: if I `MATCH(WORD,TITLE,0)`, `Agency` does not equal `Agency_Solutions` (or `Agency Solutions`; I used `SUBSTITUTE` to create 'clean' versions of the all the titles) and doesn't get weighted. If I `SEARCH(WORD,TITLE)` I weight `a` because `a` appears in `Agency_Solutions`. `FIND` would return identical results to `SEARCH` in this instance. Rock. Hard place.

I've tried a couple iterations of things, but never get results that identify the keyword as a standalone substring within the document name. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's some data

Exclusion List (paste into col A)

```
a
an
is
the
what
when
who
```

Document, keyword, count (Cols B, C, & D)

```
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt the 15
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt an  15
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt a   14
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt when    12
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt system  8
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt keyboard    8
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt mouse   8
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt when    9
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt what    9
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt who 8
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt is  8
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt phone   6
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt help    6
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt desk    5
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt cable   4
Keyboard_and_mouse_problems.txt jack    4

Agency_Solutions.txt    X   2
Agency_Solutions.txt    c   1
Agency_Solutions.txt    on  1
```

Then, my formulae:

```
Col E   =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$A$225,1,0),"notFound")    Is this in the exclusion list?
Col F   =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$A$225,1,0),"")        Exclude this word
Col G   =IF(F2=C2,0,C2)                     Include this word
Col H   =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2,B2)),100,0)          Title Weight
Col I   =IF(G2=0,0,D2+H2)                   Weighted Keywords
Col J   =IF(AND(H2=100,G2=0),"BAD","OK")            OK or Bad calculations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have spaces between words you can search for the word with spaces either side to avoid partial matches, e.g.

`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&WORD&" "," "&TITLE&" "))`

....although that falls over if you have punctuation like _ or . in TITLE.....but you can use any number of `SUBSTITUTE` functions to replace those with spaces like this

`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&WORD&" "," "&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TITLE,"_"," "),"."," ")&" "))`

Comment: Then we have something like "Agency...." which DOESN'T have a space. :| But good idea; I'd thought of that too. :)

Comment: Do you mean a title that starts with "Agency....."? My suggestion caters for that because it adds spaces to the start and end of the title too - did you try it? If WORD is `Agency` and TITLE is `Agency appleton` then the first formula returns TRUE, but with the same TITLE you'd get FALSE for `apple` because it's not a full match

Comment: Y'know, I totally didn't see the spaces on either end of the title. That may work for me. Let me give it a spin. Good call!

Answer (score 3):

You should give a try to `VLOOKUP` with wildcards, e.g. if we have `apple` in `A1`, `=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*";B:C;2;0)` will match any string that has `apple` regardless of position. See for more my other answer: https://superuser.com/a/552742/187330

Tip: to avoid case-sensetivity, use `LOWER` function for comparing.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter L. This question is my next challenge after `VLOOKUP`ing the universe per the post you mention above. My problem now is how to include `apple` while also EXCLUDING `appleton`. ...Or, how to exclude `apple` while INCLUDING `appleton`. I'm not sure I can do that in the same function.

Comment: Please provide full list (or at least a relevant sample) of your strings array.

Comment: @dwwilson66 I think I have a solution, but I'd rather test it on real data instead of generating fake samples.

Comment: @dwwilson66 add it as text to original post via edit, just 10-20 strings with mentioned "apples")

Comment: Done and done. When all the data & formulae are pasted into the appropriate columns, Col J will display `OK` or `BAD` based on what I expect in Col I.

Comment: @dwwilson66 sample is nice and makes the task much more clear. however, i also need a couple of samples for the case `apple`/`appleton` - where 1 keyword is inside the other. 2-3 such actual pairs would be just fine.

Comment: `a` and `an` are substrings of `Keyboard_and_Mouse_Problems`, so they're flagged as weighted keywords. I've also included three rows with the document title `Agency_Solutions.txt`; `x`, `c`, and `on` should be excluded from the list of weighted keywords, however, I have them included with my formulae.